# Минимальный делитель

Tags: python

Найдите самый маленький натуральный делитель числа x, отличный от 1.

Входные данные:

Вводится натуральное число x(2 <= x <= 30000).

Выходные данные:

Выведите наименьший делитель числа x, отличный от 1.

Хотел бы узнать, возможно ли решение без использования break?

```
x = int(input())

for i in range(2, x + 1):
    if x % i == 0:
        print(i)
        break
```

Comment: `print(next(i for i in range(2, x + 1) if x % i == 0))`.

Answer (score 4):

```js
function smallestDivider(n) {
  if (n % 2 == 0) return 2;
  var d = 3, stop = Math.sqrt(n);
  while (n % d && d <= stop) d += 2;
  return d <= stop? d : n;
}

console.log(961, smallestDivider(961));
console.log(97, smallestDivider(97));
console.log(1027, smallestDivider(1027));
console.log(29999, smallestDivider(29999));
```

или

```js
function smallestDivider(n) {
  if (n % 2 == 0) return 2;
  var stop = Math.sqrt(n);
  for (var d = 3; d <= stop; d += 2)
    if (n % d == 0) return d;
  return n;
}

console.log(961, smallestDivider(961));
console.log(97, smallestDivider(97));
console.log(1027, smallestDivider(1027));
console.log(29999, smallestDivider(29999));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение по этой задаче:

```
n = int(input())
i = 2
while n % i != 0:
    i += 1
print(i)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]