# Количество делителей

Tags: python

Подсчитайте количество натуральных делителей числа x (включая 1 и само число).

Входные данные
Вводится натуральное число x.

Выходные данные
Выведите единственное число - количество делителей числа x.

В 2 из 17 тестах пишет превышено максимальное время работы, как исправить?
В решении можно использовать только цикл for, без while.

```
x = int(input())

if x == 1:
    d = 1
else:
    d = 2
    for i in range(2, int((x/2) + 1)):
        if x % i == 0:
            d += 1

print(d)
```

Comment: Старайтесь чему-то научиться из ответов, которые Вы здесь получаете. Я уже показал Вам, как это сделать гораздо быстрее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042413

Comment: *как исправить?* Не использовать цикл. Использовать разложение на множители с последующим подсчётом количества сочетаний.

Comment: Хм, минусы - не мои :).

Comment: Я стараюсь использовать ответы полученные на stackoverflow, но эта задача в теме цикл for и должна решаться с использованием только его, без while

Comment: Такие вещи надо писать в вопросе.

Comment: Хорошо, учту. Но вопрос остаётся открытым

Answer (score 2):

Проверять на 1 и само число не нужно. Проверку нужно делать до х/2, т.к. от х/2 до х ни одного делителя нет.

```
d = 2 # 1 и само число
for i in range(2, int(x/2)+1): #
    if x % i == 0:
        d += 1
```

Comment: Спасибо, но в range нужен int, а если (x + 1)/2 переводить в int, то у четных чисел ответ будет на 1 меньше.

Comment: Как раз не будет.

Comment: Хотя если число нечетное, то оно на 2 не делится все равно. Так что +1 можно убрать.

Comment: Попробуйте, с четными числами ваш вариант не работает. И еще если сразу d=2, надо рассмотреть 1 отдельно. В вопросе прикрепил переделанное решение с использованием вашего ответа, но все равно пишет в 2 тестах, что превышено максимальное время работы

Comment: Подправил. Про скорость больше ничего не могу сказать.

Answer (score 1):

Все-таки напишу вариант с while не требующий излишнего перебора для больших составных чисел

```
def findDevNum(n): # number of devisors of n
    i = 2
    degree = 0
    result = 1
    while n >= 1:
        if n%i == 0:
            degree += 1
            n = n // i
        else:
            result *= (degree+1)
            degree = 0
            i += 1
            if n == 1: return result
```

Любопытно, можно ли сделать его быстрее, если хранить список простых чисел. Иными словами, что быстрее для больших n: проверять наличие i в списке накопленных простых или делить n на i.

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/793907)

Answer (score 1):

Поиск количества делителей, в которых используется перебор исходного числа неэффективен по времени при работе с большими числами. Для ускорения решения по времени, я воспользовался алгоритмом факторизации больших чисел. Данный способ на числах до 10^12 выполняется менее чем за 1 секунду

```
def number_of_divisors(n):
    i = 1
    o = 0
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0 and i * i != n:
            o += 2
        elif n % i == 0 and i * i == n:
            o += 1
        i += 1
    return o


print(number_of_divisors(9876543212345))
```

Результат: `8`

Время выполнения: `0.6562850475311279`

---

Если необходимо использовать только цикл `for`, то можно воспользоваться таким способом. В нем я уложился в 1 секунду на числах до 10^13

```
def number_of_divisors(n):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(1, math.isqrt(n) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            counter += 1
            if i * i != n:
                counter += 1
    return counter


print(number_of_divisors(98765432123456))
```

Результат: `84`

Время выполнения: `0.6412129402160645`

Comment: `int(n ** 0.5 + 1)` -> `math.isqrt(n) + 1`.

Comment: `i != n // i` -> `i * i != n`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо за комментарий, да, вычисление корня несколько ускоряет процесс(в моем случае на 0.03 сек), однако не во всех тренажерах, допустимо использование библиотек, даже встроенной math. А задание явно учебное. По поводу второй правки я не ощутил разницы. Разница по времени увеличилась на 0.003 сек. Возможно я что - то не понимаю

Comment: 1. Вещественный корень будет давать ошибки на больших числах (могу показать, если сомневаетесь). Нигде не встречал запрет `math`. 2. Деление всегда медленнее умножения, но оба варианта верные. Другое дело, что проверку на равенство делителей можно совсем убрать из цикла, подрастёт скорость.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy? Понял. Тогда приму эти правки в ответ